# Configuring custom URL binding for Workflow Manager

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, configuration, workflow-manager, workflow-manager-farm

I have a Workflow Manager farm which consists of 3 dedicated servers for Workflow Managers and 4 Workflow Manager Client (SharePoint installed) servers. The URL for Workflow Manager is like https://myservername.mydomain.com:12290 since its on HTTPS.

Is it possible to configure the URL like https://workflow.domain.com instead of the server name?

I basically want to set DNS load balancing for the incoming requests and also need to have a friendly URL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the FQDN for your workflow manager. You have to create the DNS pointing to that server / Load balancer.if you have multiple servers than make sure in your SSL certificates all the servers name included.

check this blog for more information: https://andreasglaser.com/blog/sharepoint-2019-workflow-manager#requirements

Comment: I followed the article, but i am not sure how i should add the custom binding? I tried through IIS by editing the default binding, however it started prompting for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change the IIS binding on any of the WFM servers. Just make sure that the URL you want for the Workflow Manager is included in the SSL certificate or in the SAN of the certificate.
Next configure the Load balancer for this URL to balance the load between the 3 WFM servers